# Como validar decimales asp c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, aplicación-web

Quisiera saber cómo poder validar un valor decimal en un `TextBox`, lo que pasa es que cuando escriba un decimal ejemplo `12..00`  o `12...55` se cae mi sistema, quiero que se validen solo el punto y un solo punto en ASP C#.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TxtMontoPagado" runat="server" placeholder="Monto Pagado"  Width="140px" Enabled="True"   class="form-control" title="Ingrese el Monto" data-error-msg="Ingrese el Monto" ></asp:TextBox>

<cc1:FilteredTextBoxExtender ID="FilteredTextBoxExtender8" runat="server" FilterType="Numbers, Custom" ValidChars=".," TargetControlID="TxtMontoPagado" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes utilizar `asp:RegularExpressionValidator` para que te valide valores decimales a dos posiciones:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TxtMontoPagado" runat="server" placeholder="Monto Pagado"  Width="140px" Enabled="True" class="form-control" title="Ingrese el Monto" data-error-msg="Ingrese el Monto" ></asp:TextBox>

<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegexDecimal" runat="server" ValidationExpression="((\d+)((\.\d{1,2})?))$" ErrorMessage="Ingrese un monto decimal" places." ControlToValidate="TxtMontoPagado" />
```

**Actualización**:

Si deseas mostrar el mensaje de validación en un `alert` se tendría que agregar:

```
<asp:ValidationSummary runat="server" ShowMessageBox="true" ShowSummary="false" />
```

Debajo de `asp:RegularExpressionValidator`. Aquí puedes ver la <kbd>[demostración](http://code.runnable.com/WNgx3EKfWnt3DJ7J/validators-for-net)</kbd> (dale **`Run`** para correr el proyecto).

Comment: Mil Gracias @Flxtr . una consulta como podria hacer para que ese mensaje que sale como texto de decimales pueda hacerla como un mensaje de alerta ?

Comment: Hola @Pierro , actualicé mi respuesta, esa es la forma más sencilla para mostrar una alerta de la validación. Si deseas un comportamiento diferente se requiere hacer uso de JavaScript y más código :)

Comment: eres excelente de verdad si justo eso estaba haciendo con jquery un modal algo asi actualizare mi pregunta . soy nuevo en esto la verdad sabes demasiado .

Comment: yo lo estoy haciendo con jquery javascript pero no me logra salir con ese efecto . sabes algun libro que me recomiendes quisiera ser como tu aprender soy nuevo en c#

Comment: Muchas gracias, todos empezamos por algo, lo importante es no dejar de persistir. Ahora, con la edición de tu pregunta no se entiende realmente lo que requieres o el por qué del código en el *code behind*. Te sugiero dejar esta pregunta como estaba y formular una nueva, esto con el fin de no ir arruinando lo que se pide en un inicio e ir dejando una base de conocimientos más estable y robusta :)

Comment: @Pierro ¿te parece si lo discutimos en un chat y dejamos esta pregunta como estaba anteriormente?

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56078/discussion-between-flxtr-and-pierro).

Comment: Si tienes muchas razon @Flxtr siempre hay que persistir para querer aprender o lograr cualquier cosa yo bueno en mi caso me he comprado libro de c# pero basico window form y un libro de asp pero no mucho con metodologia 3 capas pero es malo porque todo lo realizo con datatable pero en fin te agradesco un monton y si claro formulare otra pregunta . te agradesco de corazon