# Realizar popup ASP jQuery C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, aplicación-web

Quiero realizar como una alerta pero con jQuery, es decir, si sale algo malo que muestre la alerta como un `popup`.
Es decir en este momento sí realiza la validacion pero con un `alert` de JavaScript yo quiero que sea mas *amigable* para eso estoy realizando con jQuery.

Este es mi código actual.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function ShowPopup(message) {
    $(function () {
        $("#dialog").html(message);
        $("#dialog").dialog({
            title: "jQuery Dialog Popup",
            buttons: {
                Close: function () {
                    $(this).dialog('close');
                }
            },
            modal: true
        });
    });
};
</script>
```

```
asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
    /asp:ScriptManager>
    asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
        ContentTemplate>
            div id="dialog" style="display: none">
            /div>
            asp:TextBox ID="txtnumero" runat="server">
        asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegexDecimal" runat="server" ValidationExpression="((\d+)((\.\d{1,2})?))$" ErrorMessage="Ingrese un monto decimal"  ControlToValidate="txtnumero" />
       asp:ValidationSummary runat="server" ShowMessageBox="true" ShowSummary="false" />
            asp:Button ID="btnShowPopup" runat="server" Text="Guardar" OnClick="btnShowPopup_Click" />
        /ContentTemplate>
    /asp:UpdatePanel>
    /form>
```

En el *code behind*:

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=PIEROFLORES-PC;Password=123456789;Initial Catalog=colegio;Integrated Security=True"))
{
    string sql = @"Insert into numero (numero) 
    values(@numero)";
    conn.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@numero", txtnumero.Text);
    string message = "Message from server side";
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript((sender as Control), this.GetType(), "Popup", "ShowPopup('" + message + "');", true);
}
```

Como ejemplo así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Deberías al menos capturar el error, revisa: [Cómo: Utilizar el bloque Try/Catch para detectar excepciones](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/xtd0s8kd(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: @Davlio si el problema es que es decimal el caracter y cuando yo digito lo pongo asi para registrar 50...5 por eso es el error .

pero el javascript me debe arrojar el mensaje de error como un modal

Answer (score 1):

Siguiendo el hilo de [la pregunta anterior](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/57952/como-validar-decimales-asp-c), me parece que debemos ver el problema desde una perspectiva diferente. De inicio, el *plugin* que muestras de ejemplo realiza una llamada al servidor, lo cual nos la podemos ahorrar realizando las validaciones del lado del cliente con JavaScript y jQuery.

Para este ejemplo utilicé el el *plugin* <kbd>[iOS Style Dialog Plugin](http://www.jqueryscript.net/other/iOS-Style-Dialog-Popup-Plugin-For-jQuery-Modal-js.html)</kbd> pero en la red hay infinidad de *plugins* esperando ser usados, éste es bastante sencillo de implementar y usar.

Referencias a hojas de estilos, jQuery y el mismo *plugin* (estos van en la sección dentro del `<head>`):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="modal.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="modal.js"></script>
<style>
body { overflow:hidden;}
.container { margin-top:70px;}
    .color-red { color: red; }
    .bg-blue{ background-color: blue; }
</style>
```

Recuerda descargar los archivos `modal.css` y `modal.js`, ubicarlos en alguna carpeta, en este caso yo los puse en la carpeta raíz.

Función de JavaScript para validar la entrada del usuario (de igual forma la puse en la sección del `<head>`):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function validaEntradaUsuario() {
        var input = document.getElementById('<%=txtMonto.ClientID %>').value;
        if (/^\d+$/.test(input) || /^(\d+\.?\d{0,9}|\.\d{1,9})$/.test(input)) {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            $.alert('Ingrese un monto válido');
            return false;
        }
    }
</script>
```

Contenido de la página y controles de usuario:

```
<div>
    <label>Monto:</label><br />
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtMonto" runat="server" CssClass="txtInput"></asp:TextBox>
</div>
<div>
    <br />
    <asp:Button ID="btnSubmitForm" runat="server" Text="Submit Form" OnClick="btnSubmitForm_Click" OnClientClick="return validaEntradaUsuario();" />
</div>
```

Básicamente, al hacer el `Submit` del formulario se ejecuta `OnClientClick="return validaEntradaUsuario();"`, la función `validaEntradaUsuario()` de JavaScript obtiene el valor del `TextBox` y valida su contenido por medio de dos expresiones regualares, es para la validación de un monto entero o que incluya decimales, finalmente, si todo sale bien continúa la ejecución del código, caso contrario, se muestra el mensaje de error.

Nota: puse a propósito algunas cosas de forma estática, es decir, hay algunas cosas que se pueden automatizar y te pueden funcionar para uno o más controles, todo es parte del proceso de aprendizaje.

Comment: mi gran amigo me salio un error como este :

La colección de controles no puede modificarse porque el control contiene bloques de código (por ej. <% ... %>).

Comment: lo subire la foto del error o si me das tu correo te puedo pasar todo lo que estoy haciendo .

Comment: @Pierro en lugar de poner el bloque de código con `<%=` ponle `<%#`, eso debería ser justo en donde haces la llamada para obtener el Id del control

Comment: amigo ahora parece que no valida porque cuando pongo en guardar me sale este error lo pondre en mi pregunta.
te quise enviar el correo pero me indica que tu lo rechasaste

Comment: Si no se puede enviar a tu correo te doy mi clave y contraseña y ingresas mi gran amigo.
Lo llamare proyectoFLxtr y lo descargas

Comment: @Pierro discúlpame, he andado bien ocupado con el trabajo, dame una hora aprox y te envío el proyecto completo :)

Comment: no te preocupes mas bien te agradesco demasido.
mi correo es : pierofloresespinoza@gmail.com

te estuve enviando mi proyecto no me rechases amigo

Comment: si me llego tu correo muchas gracias yo tamien te envie mi proyecto completo amigo